# Inconsistent behavior of view parameters between view and render helpers

Tags: ember.js

I've stumbled across an inconsistency regarding view parameters between the *view* and *render* helpers.
Please take a look at this JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/zazeguhufi/1/edit?html,js,output

As you can see, when using the *view* helper, both view parameters (string "foo" and variable "App.bar") are properly rendered in the output.

But when using *render*, only the first view parameter (string "foo") is rendered. The other parameter (var "App.bar") seems to get lost somehow and is set to the default value defined in the *messages* view.

So I'm not sure, whether this is a bug or the intended behavior, but it seems kind of strange to me.

Thanks,
Flip

Comment: Global lookup of views are depracated. Might be one of the issues. http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_global-lookup-of-views

Comment: Thanks, but this example uses 1.7. Here is an updated version using 1.8.1 - still showing the same behavior: http://jsbin.com/kalurusumo/1/edit?html,js,output